# Error starting Rails server: "unexpected .."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I set up a Rails app on OpenShift and pulled the default code. When I tried running it, I got the following error:

```
C:/Development/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load': C:/HEATH3N/FirstApp/config/initializers/session_store.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected .. (SyntaxError)
../../.openshift/lib/session_store.rb
```

I'm unclear as to what the problem is. I looked at the problematic file and don't see anything wrong. I found other questions on Stack Overflow asking about another problem with the file (the new hash style isn't supported on older Ruby versions) but I'm using Ruby 2.3 (Rails 4.1.4) and my error is different.

```
require File.join(Rails.root,'lib','openshift_secret_generator.rb')

# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Set token based on intialize_secret function (defined in initializers/secret_generator.rb)

Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => initialize_secret(
  :session_store,
  '_railsapp_session'
)

# Use the database for sessions instead of the cookie-based default,
# which shouldn't be used to store highly confidential information
# (create the session table with "rails generate session_migration")
# RailsApp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```

Comment: Can you post the file?

Comment: Oh right, sorry...updated the question.

Comment: What do you see when you open rails console and type `RUBY_VERSION`?

Comment: I can't access the console without getting that error. Running `ruby -v` gives me `ruby 2.3.0p0` and I checked the SDK settings in RubyMine and it says it's using that.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Rails version 4.1.4

Answer (score 0):

Try something like so -

```
require File.expand_path(‘../lib/openshift_secret_generator.rb‘, __FILE__)
```

or

```
require Rails.root.join('lib', 'openshift_secret_generator.rb').to_s
```

Please do update if either or both work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately neither made any difference.

Comment: Also, just to make sure, did you restart the server after making changes?

Comment: I restarted the server but there was no change in error.